# bind event didn't work in render function

Tags: vue.js, vue-render-function

this is the component BadCodeSelector, it emit an function confirm, when button clicked, the method confirm worked.

```
<template>
 <div class="BadCodeSelector-buttons">
    <el-button size="small" type="warning" @click="beforeClose">取消</el-button>
    <el-button
      size="small"
      type="primary"
      @click="confirm"
    >
      确定
    </el-button>
  </div>
</template>

<javascript>
export default {
  props: {
    materialTypeCode: String,
    activeRow: Object
  },
  methods: {
     confirm() {
      this.$emit('confirm', this.badCodeData)
      console.log('confirm function emit')
    },
  }

}

</javascript>
```

but in the render function, the  confirm function did't work

```
onShowBadCodeSelector(row) {
  const hide = this.$dialog.show({
    dialogProps: {
      title: '不良代码'
    },
    render: () => {
      return (
      <BadCodeSelector
        materialTypeCode={this.mainFormData.materialTypeCode}
        activeRow={row}
        v-on:confirm={confirm}
      />
    )
    }
  })
  const confirm = data => {
    console.log('function emited')
    hide()
  }
}
```

the function in component worked, but didn't work in onShowBadCodeSelector

the  confirm function work in render function

Comment: The vue version is 2.5.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSX the event should have this syntax `onEventName`, `on`+`EventName` capitalized :

```html
   <BadCodeSelector
        materialTypeCode={this.mainFormData.materialTypeCode}
        activeRow={row}
        onConfirm={confirm}
      />
```

Comment: thanks , it worked。but I have another question, v-on also worked some time。 This seems to have no pattern ， it worked in another component.

`
<BadPictureHandler
  materialTypeCode={this.mainFormData.materialTypeCode}
  activeRow={row}
  v-on:confirmBadPicture={confirmBadPicture}
  v-on:beforeClose={() => hide()}
/>

`

Comment: Please check https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-on

Comment: I found that It's not the the syntax problem,  v-on and  on+EventName are both worked. It's the function definition.  when i use 'function confirm(){}', it worked, and when its 'const onConfirm=() =>{}', it did't work.  Its an low level error i made...